# Creating an R Shiny application that writes to an Excel as well as reading from it

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently working on a shiny application to report on a business wide scale, which is working fine. However I've been asked if I can implement a means of writing information to a central document, which will then be read back into the application again on the next run.

Essentially what I need to make is a shiny app that I can input data into, and this is then retrievable at a later date. Is this achieveable with an Excel document? Organising a database within company filestructure wouldn't be allowed, so this is all I can think of.

Would this be as straightforward as using a package to write to Excel and then having an update script run at the beginning of each update or would there be more to consider? Most importantly, if two users are updating at the same time, would R wait for one update to finish before running the next one?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: didi you check this? https://deanattali.com/2015/06/14/mimicking-google-form-shiny/